# How to Write Getter and setters for fields of a standard object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

How to write getter and setters for fields of an standard object ?

for example:

```
public class Wrappercontact
{

public contact con {get;set;}
public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}

public Wrappercontact(Contact c)
{
     this.con = c;
    isSelected = false;

}

}
```

For the above wrapper class, can anyone tell me how to write getter and setters for each fields in contact object ?

Thanks

Comment: May I know your scenario why do you want a getter and setter for the fields? For your scenario, if you want to access contact fields, you just use something like wrapper.con.name.

Comment: I want to display some of the fields of contacts in one visualforce page, for avoiding any null values in those fields I want to write getter and setters for some of the fields in contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comment, I guess your requirement don't really need the getter, setter you mentioned.

In your VF page, if you need an inputField, simply use something like:

```
<apex:inputField value={!wrapper.con.name}/>
```

Null value will automatically be treated as blank.

If you really want a more complex getter, like:

```
public Integer getCount() {
    if (wrapper.con.count >= 0)
        return wrapper.con.count;
    else return 0;
}
```

You can simply write like that. And in your page, use {!Count} will be able to output the result.

If you want a bit logic before storing the value, I would recommend using javascript.